# Java unary promotion, left shift operator, and short

Tags: java, javac, jls

The JLS [§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) says:

> Some operators apply unary numeric promotion to a single operand, which must produce a value of a numeric type:
> ...
> if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion
> ...
> Unary numeric promotion is performed on expressions in the following situations:
> ...
> Each operand, separately, of a shift operator <<, >>, or >>>

That explains why this program fails to compile:

```java
public class xx {
    public short twice(short x) {
        return x << 1;
    }
}
```

with this error:

```sh
$ javac xx.java
xx.java:3: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
        return x << 1;
                 ^
1 error
```

OK. So why does this program compile successfully?

```java
public class xx {
    public short two() {
        return (short)1 << 1;
    }
}
```

Doesn't the expression `(short)1` qualify as "compile-time type byte, short, or char" ?

Here's what I'm using:

```sh
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-bre_2021_01_20_16_37-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b00, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Actually, casting in function two() doesn't change anything. I guess that compiler resolves 1<<1 as constant and replaces whole call to function with constant 2?

Answer (score 3):

The cast is a red herring here; the code compiles just the same without it. What matters is that the expression `1 << 1` is a constant expression. So sayeth the JLS ​([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.), emphasis mine):

> Assignment contexts allow the value of an expression to be assigned (§15.26) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable. [...]  **if the expression is a constant expression** (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`: A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Note that your expression occurs in a `return` statement, not in a variable assignment, but [§14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) tells us that this expression is an assignment context, so §5.2 quoted above applies.

So you have an assignment context of type `short`, and in that context you have the constant expression `1 << 1` which results in the value `2`, which is indeed representable in the type `short`. So that's why it compiles.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it had to do with being a constant expression but didn't know how exactly that was supposed to change the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've created sample code similar to your, and then checked bytecode.
Here's the code:

```
package dsa;

public class Shorts {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        short what = twice();
        System.out.println(what);
    }
    
    public static short twice() {
        return 1 << 1;
    }
    
}
```

And the generated bytecode:

```
Compiled from "Shorts.java"
public class dsa.Shorts {
  public dsa.Shorts();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #7                  // Method twice:()S
       3: istore_1
       4: getstatic     #13                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: iload_1
       8: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      11: return

  public static short twice();
    Code:
       0: iconst_2
       1: ireturn
}
```

Be aware that I'm not an expert but to me looks like compiler optimized function to return constant integer, then store it in int variable until it was printed. So the answer is, to paraphrase quote from one famous movie: "There is no short".